# how to add a code-behind page to a view or partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, code-behind

I notice with the latest version of ASP.NET MVC that a View no longer defaults to having code-behind classes.

How do I go about adding a code-behind class now to a View or Partial View??

Comment: How about changing the title to read How to add a code-behind page to any view

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**How to add a Code-behind page to a Partial View**

Seems this wasn't particularly tricky, and is quite do-able. This answer worked for a Partial `ViewUserControl` but the same should apply for a Normal MVC `ViewPage` as well

1. Add a new Class file with the convention of `<view filename & extention>.cs`  (i.e. `view.ascx.cs`)
2. Add `using System.Web.Mvc;` to the class
3. Change the class to Inherit from `ViewUserControl<>`. 
   i.e. `public class Foo:ViewUserControl`
4. Add the following to the View's header:

   `CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.Views.Shared.View"`
5. Copy the files out of the solution and drag back in to re-associate the two together. This may not be necessary in VS 2010+ and MVC 2+.

For this to work with a normal MVC View, you just need to inherit the class from "ViewPage"

Comment: Thanks for that. I've found a quicker way to associate the two files together is to right-click them, choose Exclude From Project, then with 'Show All Files' selected right-click them again and re-include them.

Comment: VS2010 associates them as soon as you create the class blah.ascx.cs (in the same directory as the aspx page). Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you are creating a code behind file, but if you really really do, then I would consider using the standard webforms approach instead.

I would also look into the basics of MVC to understand why page behinds are not needed.

[Another explanation](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/01/MVC-Strongly-Type-ViewPages-Without-A-Code-Behind.aspx)

[How to use ASP:Chart without a code-behind (Option B)](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/#scid:812469c5-0cb0-4c63-8c15-c81123a09de7:978c0f32-5e2a-4d51-9241-4d3827904d13)

Comment: It's quite simple really.  I need to use code behind to populate the Chart series i'm using.  It wouldn't let me use a normal MVC approach.  This is a REAL world compromise, and it works.

Comment: In that case, here is how you can use Chart without a code-behind:

http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: So are you telling me you would prefer to have very messy hard to manage spaghetti code in your html?  I think this is very valid use of code behind.  It is not controller logic, it isn't presentation code.  it is presentation preparation.

Comment: You don't *have* to put all of that code in the view. It's merely put there to show the user that they don't need to use code-behinds to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have verified the solution, here is something that you need to note:

CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.Views.Shared.View"

In your case, you need to change "Project.Views.Shared.View" based on your namespace and classname, and in order to access the control in the code-behind, you have to manually add declaration in code-behind. In my case, I need to initialize the gigaSoft proEssential control:

```
public class gigaTest2 : ViewUserControl
{
    protected global::Gigasoft.ProEssentials.PegoWeb PegoWeb1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set Titles 
        PegoWeb1.PeString.MainTitle = "Hello ASP.NET";
        PegoWeb1.PeString.SubTitle = "";

        // One simple way of passing data, data binding also possible. //' 
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Subsets = 1;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Points = 6;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 0] = 10;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 1] = 30;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 2] = 20;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 3] = 40;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 4] = 30;
        PegoWeb1.PeData.Y[0, 5] = 50;

        // Set style of chart and a few other properties //' 
        PegoWeb1.PePlot.Method = Gigasoft.ProEssentials.Enums.GraphPlottingMethod.Bar;
        PegoWeb1.PePlot.Option.GradientBars = 8;
        PegoWeb1.PeFont.FontSize = Gigasoft.ProEssentials.Enums.FontSize.Large;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a codebehind file to your aspx page, while still allowing it to be the target of an MVC view, do the following.

For a view page named `Index.aspx`...

Replace the following code....

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Page CodeFile="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Home_Index" %>
```

Then create a file called `Index.aspx.cs` (or `.vb`).

```
partial class Home_Index : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{...}
```

or VB

```
Partial Class Home_Index
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
    ...
End Class
```

That's it.  The only thing special is using the correct `Mvc.ViewPage` base class.