# Where have the Mvc Code behind files gone?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 2 (RC) I do not see the Codebehind files, Have they been deliberately remvoed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a proper install of MVC 1, the codebehind files would already be gone. They are sometimes considered harmfull as they are likely to violate the MVC pattern.

Codebehind is still possible though, yet you'll need to add them by hand. See f.e. [how to add a code-behind page to a view or partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680448/asp-net-mvc-how-to-add-a-code-behind-page-to-a-view).

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to codebehind in MVC would be the controller, although it's not really comparable since the controller have no clue of whats going on in the view.